# Is a promotional grant for Star Wars: The Complete Saga on Blu-Ray wanted?

Tags: discussion

This is more last-minute than I usually like to propose grants, but I just realized that the release of **[Star Wars: The Complete Saga](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZSJ212)** on Blu-Ray on September 16th is probably going to be...a big deal. The internet seems ready to crack in half over the changes and special features included on the release. The changes themselves have proven to be quite controversial (the only semi-comprehensive list I have been able to find is [here](http://www.toplessrobot.com/2011/08/all_the_star_wars_blu-ray_changes_for_your_viewing.php); *please link to a better list if you are aware of one!*).

I think this would be a good thing to provide for the following reasons:

- *Star Wars* is currently the second most popular franchise-related tag
  on the site, and the third most popular tag overall. People like
  talking about *Star Wars* on this site.
- The amount of attention being placed on the *Star Wars* Blu-Ray release
  is already overwhelming. When the actual Blu-Rays are released, I
  imagine the popularity will increase. There will be a lot of *Star
  Wars* Googling and if we have a lot of great *Star Wars* content it can
  only help promote the site.
- These Blu-Rays have a ridiculous amount of trivia already built in
  thanks to the changes and special features. I'm sure that a lot of
  these changes and deleted scenes will inspire questions about why they were made/cut, what
  they mean for the canon's continuity and how they differ from
  previous versions (Lucas has been [tinkering with the films for
  decades](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_changes_in_Star_Wars_re-releases), even between VHS releases in the '80s and '90s).

---

So I propose:

- (X) number of users receive a copy of **Star Wars: The Complete Saga** on Blu-Ray
- As [DampeS8N](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/51/dampes8n) comments below, priority may be given to high-reputation users who have never seen one/most/all of the 6 *Star Wars* films. A fresh perspective would be **incredibly valuable** in attracting new users. Granted, I don't have the ability to prove that these users haven't seen the films. Let's do it honest, people, and trust each other. *We are all buds*.
- Users must have the capability to play Blu-Ray discs; Stack Exchange will not provide one
- The recipients will be encouraged to [ask thoughtful questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) about *Star Wars* in general and/or the Blu-Rays in particular. These same users (as well as all of our users) are encouraged to be "on call" and ready to answer any related questions that pop up about the trilogies and Blu-Ray release. [Blogging](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/) would also be encouraged.

---

If this sounds like fun, please discuss it below. If there's enough interest and support over the next few days, I will start the official grant process on Monday, September 12th.

---

**EDIT:** The grant is [up and running](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/773/promotional-grant-star-wars-the-complete-saga-on-blu-ray)!

Comment: Especially people who have not seen these films yet should toss their hat into the ring. Getting a 'first watch' perspective on these is HARD.

Comment: This is definitely a good suggestion. I don't know if I'd quality, I've watched Star Wars before, but I probably haven't watched every second of it. Hmmm.

Comment: Star Wars is the one where they fight in that space station next to the wormhole.  Right?  I think the captain's black and there's a shape-shifter in that one.

Comment: @Kalamane: No, I'm pretty sure Star Wars is the one with that guy from Quantum Leap and a really cheesy theme song.

Comment: I thought Star Wars was the one with Hercules as the captain.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris I think you're right.

Comment: Oh wait... We weren't talking about the show with the big circular gates?

Comment: I like this plan, but we'd have to confirm people have a Blu-Ray player as well. Given enough reputation on this site for the users interested, I could support including a player in the grant; amazon has a bunch at around $100: http://goo.gl/WEqSb

Comment: @Jeff And what about an HDTV? I'm sure you could find a bunch of reasonably priced ones! I would even be ready to review the [Holiday Special](http://theforce.net/latestnews/story/the_holiday_special_coming_to_bluray_137440.asp) to get one!  :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if no one else will stand up and apply, I will.  I'm an A/V geek on the side, so I already have a blu-ray player and HDTV, so I'm set on the technical requirements front.  I'm a big fan of Star Wars, but mostly the movies and TV shows, as I'm not much of a book reader.  This is why I dont have too many Star Wars questions and answers on the site, as many of those are EU-focused.  Most of my Star Wars expertise comes from the original movies and the currently-running The Clone Wars show, which I'm a huge fan of and own the blu-rays of already (the show, not the movies!).