# Promotional Grant - Star Wars: The Complete Saga on Blu-Ray

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

**[Star Wars: The Complete Saga](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZSJ212)** on Blu-Ray is being released on Friday, September 16th. To make sure that our site is the best place on the internet to ask and answer *Star Wars* questions, we are providing our users with copies of the Blu-Ray.

Here's how it will work:

- **Up to 10 users** will receive the **Star Wars: The Complete Saga** on Blu-Ray box set. This [box set includes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZSJ212) all 6 *Star Wars* films as well as 3 discs of bonus materials.
- **To enter, post your username as an answer to this question.** The 10 users with the **highest rep at the time of the voting's closing** will receive the box set. Votes have no bearing on the outcome of this grant, only reputation. This contest is open to EVERYONE on Stack Exchange, regardless of whether or not you have seen the movies before. A fresh perspective would be **incredibly valuable** in attracting new users, so if you are a *Star Wars* newbie, do not shy away!
- **Users must be able to play Blu-Ray discs**, as Blu-Ray players will not be provided as part of this grant. If you will not be able to play this Blu-Ray box set upon receiving it, do not put your name into the running.
- If there are particular pre-order deals, sales, or other goodies you
  can think of or find, those would be helpful to determining which
  distributor to purchase the movies through. Be sure to
  point out any of these in your post. Odds are, all of this will be done though Amazon. **Reimbursements may need to be done if shipping to your location proves to be extraordinarily expensive or difficult.** We want all of our users to be involved and don't want crazy shipping laws to get in the way of that.
- When the voting period ends, the 10 selected users will email me their mailing address. **If you are under 18, make sure you
  or your parent/guardians are okay with the fact we're getting your
  mailing address**.
- The recipients will be encouraged to **[ask thoughtful questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)** about *Star Wars* in general and/or the Blu-Rays in particular. These same users (as well as all of our users) are encouraged to be "on call" and ready to answer any related questions that pop up about the trilogies and Blu-Ray release. [Blogging](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/) would also be encouraged.

---

Applications will be accepted until **4PM Eastern on Wednesday, September 14th**. Get to applying! Let's do this!

Comment: I... err, what?  Didn't you already make this post?  I don't see why you needed 2 separate posts on this.

Comment: Good luck everyone.

Comment: @Keen: The first post was to ask if we are interested. This post is to get the people applying.

Comment: darn - i don't have a Blu-Ray player :(

Comment: darn - already pre-ordered it, and don't want to be greedy :-S

Comment: As for the shipping and customs thing, wouldn't be better to order them from the user's [local version of Amazon](http://www.amazon.ca/Star-Wars-Complete-Saga-Blu-ray/dp/B004HZXORA/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1315930561&sr=8-1)

Comment: @DavROb60 - unfortunately, Amazon doesn't have a local presence in Australia (and many other countries) - so I guess the shipping issue reflects that.

Comment: having done a bit of international shipping I *strongly* recommend using the national Amazons when possible. that is amazon.co.uk and amazon.de among others. (No there is no easy way to reach Australia)

Comment: @HorusKol But, is there any online library, retailer or [General Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_store) that deserve Australia's domestic online market at a fair prices? That may be a better choice than the generic Amazon.com.

Comment: @HorusKol If there's no local Amazon, surely there's some local online store that sells blu-rays.  Buying from a different area and shipping it internationally can potentially cause issues due to blu-rays having region locks.

Comment: @DavRob60 and Keen - yeah, there are other options, but I (mis)read the original post that this was going to be handled all through Amazon. I was just trying to point out why the caveat on shipping and reimbursement would be needed - it is not necessarily true that everyone is able to get a free shipped version from a local source.

Comment: Of course we are going to go through national Amazons when possible. I am sorry for assuming that that would be assumed.

Comment: I thought about applying for this, but the cheapest one I could find online here in germany was around US$120. Since the UK and US ones are _significantly_ cheaper, I decided against it, as I don't want to cause you extra costs ...

Comment: Ah crap. I'm here too late...

Comment: @BrettWhite - is there a consolation grant anywhere in the plans? As someone who was in the top 3 overall users since forever, top 2 all-time answerer for [SW] tag (and #6 asker); and 2 both asker and answerer on [harry-potter] tag, I feel all depressed about missing out on the grants :(   Something like lifetime achievement award may be? :))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following users will receive copies.

- Pearsonartphoto
- Keen
- DavRob60
- Jeff
- OghmaOsiris
- Mike Scott

Please email your mailing address to **brett [at] stackexchange [dot] com** as soon as possible and we will get these ordered. Thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 0):

Keen

I'm an A/V geek on the side, so I already have a blu-ray player and HDTV, so I'm set on the technical requirements front. I'm a big fan of Star Wars, but mostly the movies and TV shows, as I'm not much of a book reader. This is why I dont have too many Star Wars questions and answers on the site, as many of those are EU-focused. Most of my Star Wars expertise comes from the original movies and the currently-running The Clone Wars show, which I'm a huge fan of and own the blu-rays of already (the show, not the movies!).

Comment: Any interest in writing something for the blog about this?  It can be short, and about anything related to SW that you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Pearsonartphoto

I'm not the hugest SW fan, but I would like to see the entire series on Blu-ray, and I'd be willing to do an outsider's take on Star Wars. Maybe I'll even be able to answer a few questions:-) I do have a decent TV/AV equipment, as well as a blu-ray player.

Comment: Any interest in writing something for the blog about this?  It can be short, and about anything related to SW that you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

DavRob60

In [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars), I'm currently [the 4th Answerer and 2th Asker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/star-wars/topusers).

Honestly, I dont have a blue-ray (yet), but my father in law has one. He is a science fiction fan, but he is more of the Star Trek type and I'm pretty sure he did not view those movies since theirs original theatrical release. Anyway, he lives at 15 minutes form my home and my kids didn't saw those movies yet. So I'm sure he will be willing for some family movie nights.

Finally, I cant wait to see if [Han Solo officially shoot first](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2286/in-canon-does-han-solo-shoot-first).

Comment: Any interest in writing something for the blog about this?  It can be short, and about anything related to SW that you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Scott

I have all of the movies on DVD already, but I've not read any tie-in novels since *Splinter of the Mind's Eye* (i.e. not for about three decades).

There don't seem to be any offers in the UK, but I have Amazon Prime (UK version) which might help with shipping.

Comment: Any interest in writing something for the blog about this?  It can be short, and about anything related to SW that you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

OghmaOsiris

I'm more of a Star Trek fan, but I do love Star Wars. I actually haven't seen Star Wars fore quite a few years now. It would be nice to watch all the movies back to back as I've never done that before.

I would also love to watch them in [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/in-what-order-should-the-star-wars-movies-be-watched) order as that seems to be the recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff

I do NOT own a Blu-Ray player, however I have ready access to them from two different sources: my work laptop (which I may bring home) and my father's place.  Hell, my father may have one I can borrow for an extended period.

Comment: Any interest in writing something for the blog about this?  It can be short, and about anything related to SW that you'd like.