# Upcoming movies/ books that would be of interest

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

In the spirit of [this gaming post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/gaming-promotional-grant-fall-2011-game-selection-thread), and the [current promotional grant here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/773/promotional-grant-star-wars-the-complete-saga-on-blu-ray), I'd like to ask, what else do you think we might be able to give away, in an effort to help this site? Specifically, I would like to see names of upcoming books/ movies/ etc which numerable people might be interested in, which if we can seed several copies around, might work for us.

Off the top of my head, I can think of these:

- [Inheritance](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0375856110)
- [Heroes of Olympus, The, Book Two: The Son of Neptune](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1423140591)
- [Green Lantern](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005I64U5C)
- [Harry Potter 7 part 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001UV4XJ2)
- [Jurassic Park Ultimate Trilogy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0057R5XRG)

It would also be interesting to do the same for movies which are currently in a theater (Providing tickets to watch, I'm assuming minimum 2 at a time).

Comment: Thor just came out today on Blu-ray/DVD.  Captain America will be released in October.

Answer (score 3):

[A Dance with Dragons: A Song of Ice and Fire](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553801473) was released a few months ago, but is very high profile because (a) Martin took forever to finish this book, and (b) the *Game of Thrones* TV series that's based on this series of books.

A grant could potentially be for the entire series (or what's published so far), or just for the latest book.

Answer (score 3):

It's nearly a month since the announcement, and these were all published some time before that, but a grant for the "2011 Hugo Award Winners" would be neat:

- [Blackout/All Clear](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553807676) (Best Novel, published October 19, 2010).  Won the 2011 Nebula as well.
- [The Lifecycle of Software Objects](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1596063173) (Best Novella, published July 31, 2010).
- [The Emperor of Mars](http://www.asimovs.com/2011_06/images/611hugo_emperor.pdf) (Best Novelette, published June 2010).  No grant needed here :)
- [For Want of a Nail](http://www.asimovs.com/2011_06/images/611hugo_nail.pdf) by Mary Robinette Kowal (Best Short Story, September 2010).  No grant needed here either.
- [Chicks Dig Time Lords: A Celebration of Doctor Who by the Women Who Love It](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1935234048) (Best Related Work, published March 15, 2010).  About fandom more than the series, but still on-topic I think.
- [Girl Genius, Volume 10: Agatha Heterodyne and the Guardian Muse](http://Girl%20Genius,%20Volume%2010%3a%20Agatha%20Heterodyne%20and%20the%20Guardian%20Muse) (Best Graphic Story, published June 28, 2011).  I'm not familiar with this, so I don't know whether it matters whether you've read the earlier volumes or not.

The [Nebulas](http://www.outsidethebeltway.com/2011-nebula-award-winners/) were slightly longer ago, but might also be good choices.  Alternatively, something could be done next year with either winners or nominees.

Comment: I think doing something with next year's Hugo nominees after they're announced would be more useful -- this year's winners have already been heavily discussed online. Since most of the nominees are usually made available in electronic form to members of the Worldcon where the voting will take place, it would be simplest just to buy supporting memberships to the Worldcon for the grant recipients (around $50).

Answer (score 2):

**Tickets to:**

In Time

Contagion

Apollo 18

Don't Be Afraid of the Dark

Conan The Barbarian

Fright Night

**DVDs of:**

Thor

Captain America

X-Men First Class

Paul

Limitless

Priest

Answer (score 1):

Orson Scott Card:

- [Ender's Game: Formic Wars: Burning Earth](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785136096) (September 21, 2011).  I think this is a stand-alone prequel.
- [Shadows in Flight (The Shadow)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0765332000) (January 17, 2012).  This is another book in the *Shadows* series (a grant could be for this alone or for the series).
- [The Lost Gate (Mither Mages)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0765326574) (January 4, 2011).  Not upcoming, but relatively new.
- [Ruins (Pathfinder)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416991778) (March 6, 2012).  Sequel to last year's *Pathfinder*.
- [Laddertop, Volume 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0765324601) (September 27, 2011).  Manga, young adult, co-written with his daughter Emily Card.

Answer (score 1):

[Star Wars: Heir to the Empire: The 20th Anniversary Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345528298) has recently (September 6, 2011) been released.  This is an old book, obviously, but it's a great place to start reading the wider Star Wars universe, and coincides nicely with the current Blu-ray release of the films.

Answer (score 1):

io9 has a [fairly comprehensive list](http://io9.com/5836241/the-io9-guide-to-septembers-science-fiction-and-fantasy) of September's sci-fi releases. I assume they do this every month. It might be helpful to publish this list here as it is made available, and let the community decide from it. Unless it turns out to not be as comprehensive as it looks from first glance.

Answer (score 1):

Next week, *Batman: Year One* is released on Blu/DVD.  Week after that, *Captain America: The First Avenger is released on Blu/DVD as well.  I think these would make good promotional grant material, especially Batman, as the DC Animated Universe movies have been good sources of questions and this one covers the origins of Batman, an extremely popular character.

Answer (score 0):

New Discworld novels:

- [Snuff](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0062011847) (October 11, 2011)
- [I Shall Wear Midnight](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061433063) (September 27, 2011)

Note that the Area51 Pratchett/Discworld proposal was merged with the site, so in theory there are many Discworld fans around.  Unfortunately, given Pratchett's health, it's likely that these are among the last Discworld books he'll publish, which does make them higher profile.

Comment: I'm a bit of a *Discworld* fan, but I tend to lag a few years behind. Given my schedule, there is no way I can promise a timely response even if I was to read the book as soon as it is released.

Answer (score 0):

Goodkind's latest *Sword of Truth* novel was recently (August 16, 2011) relased: [Omen Machine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0765327724).

Like *A Song of Fire and Ice*, a series that had a [TV series based on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_the_Seeker), although it was cancelled last year.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest forthcoming SF novels are likely to be:

- *Reamde* by Neal Stephenson, published next Tuesday (20
  September).
- *The Children of the Sky* by Vernor Vinge, published on October 11.

Answer (score 0):

On February 10th, 2012, Star Wars: The Phantom Menace in 3D will hit the theaters. This would be a good opportunity to give out movie tickets.

Also, when it is eventually released on Blu-ray and DVD, there could be another giveaway for those. (It will be available other than in theaters, right?)

Comment: However, I can't say whether or not most of these StackExchange Star Wars fans would want this stuff, seeing as many of them pretend the prequel trilogy is non-existent ... ;-) Well, I guess I'll just have to rely on @Brett White loving 3D movies so much that his gravatar will start wearing 3D glasses like Tony Meyer's! :-)