# Star Wars promotion/contest ideas

Tags: site-promotion, discussion

Going through Meta, I saw the [promotional grant](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/773/promotional-grant-star-wars-the-complete-saga-on-blu-ray) for the Star Wars blu-rays from last September.  As Brent noted [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/766/is-a-promotional-grant-for-star-wars-the-complete-saga-on-blu-ray-wanted), Star Wars is one of the most popular topics here and the potential for promotion is huge.

To me this indicates that we should try a bigger contest.  Gaming has had several promotions lately that have been massively successful (from my perspective, I don't know SE's) and I think something in the same vein would work here.

Ideas:

- Wars vs Trek, a la [Skyrim vs MW3](http://skyrimvsmw3.com/).  They have almost the same number of questions in the primary tags and it's a classic (if somewhat unintuitive) matchup.  DVDs/Blu-rays are certainly potential prizes, I'm not very familiar with Star Trek though so I can't say what else would be.
- Star Wars Week.  It's been mentioned before that an annual contest coinciding with May the 4th would be awesome, but that's obviously something to consider after trying it the first time :P.  Personally, I wouldn't require May the 4th specifically, but others might feel strongly about it and it might be helpful due to the minor surge in Star Wars awareness that occurs.

  In any case, Star Wars has tons of content all by itself and I think focusing on it specifically could be even bigger than trying to draw in two groups of fans as above.  Potential prizes are the movies, games, books, action figures ... endless possibilities.

As an aside, I couldn't help but notice that the badge icons [image: icon] look like [the emblem of the Rebel Alliance](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41VosOy-8dL._SL500_AA300_.jpg).  If a contest did happen, tweaking the icons would be the best thing ever.

It might also be possible to get Lucasfilm to support something.  I don't know how unlikely that would be, probably fairly, but certainly worth trying since we could reach way more people.

Obviously SE needs to be on board here and would determine the specific format, runtime, prizes, and so on.  I hope there are some good ideas here though, I'd really like this to happen!  I have at least a hundred Star Wars questions to ask (seriously, don't even try me) and no incentive to make the time to do so.... :P

Does anyone else have any other ideas or thoughts on this?

Comment: If we wanted Lucasfilm to support us, we'd have to clean up some of the comments on the Star Wars questions, lol...

Comment: @OghmaOsiris You'd probably have to boot me off the site for the duration, too :P  I don't want George turning my neighborhood into low-income housing just to spite me!

Comment: I was actually wondering what the badge icon was supposed to represent. Thanks, this saved me the need to uselessly post a question on meta.

Answer (score 1):

The success of the Skyrim promotion (and, more recently, the [Diablo III promotion](http://diablo3acts.com)) was in no small part due to it coinciding with a very large, very hyped release for the game: people were naturally looking for an answer fix and Gaming.SE had the goods in stock.

While the Star Wars tag does pretty well here, we're by no means the only source for the information being asked, so there isn't as big an opportunity for a well-timed push for content seeding like there is with promotions for major game releases.

But is there any major Star Wars release coming up soon? I vaguely recall hearing something about the 3D re-release, but I think that's already passed.

Comment: Star Wars books are constantly coming out.  The *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* series is still airing, so that has normal TV show events (premieres, finales, DVD releases) associated with it.  The 3D rereleases are coming out each year, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Keen Skyrim/Diablo III is in a completely different league than an on-going cartoon or various EU novels: somehow, I don't think any of those things are selling 5 million copies in a week. It might make sense to time a promotion on the level of Skyrim vs. MW3 with the next 3D release, though.

Comment: I totally agree, but that's the extent of what's happening in the Star Wars universe these days.

Comment: I would say the audience for Star Wars is bigger and promotion for here not tied to an event would do better than promotion for a game not tied to an event.  This is a fair point though, certainly something for SE to consider if they were to go ahead with it.  I'm more putting the idea out there so that we can look for the right time to do it ;)